# How to calculate reliability of difference scores?

Tags: dataset, reliability, psychometrics, differences, cronbachs-alpha

I am trying to calculate the reliability of a difference score.  Specifically, the data have, for each participant, scores for 10 items in Condition X (1s and 0s), as well as 10 different items in Condition Y (1s and 0s).  The difference score is the mean of Condition X minus the mean of Condition Y.  Each participant in the study has 1 difference score.

I need to calculate the reliability of the difference score, for instance using Cronbach's alpha.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this?  Thanks in advance!